# Espresso match first element found when many are in hierarchy

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso

I'm trying to write an espresso function to match the first element espresso finds according to my function, even when multiple matching items are found.

Ex: 
I have a list view with cells which contain item price. I want to be able to switch the currency to Canadian dollars and verify item prices are in CAD.

I'm using this function:

```
    onView(anyOf(withId(R.id.product_price), withText(endsWith("CAD"))))
        .check(matches(
                isDisplayed()));
```

This throws the AmbiguousViewMatcherException.

In this case, I don't care how many or few cells display CAD, I just want to verify it is displayed. Is there way to make espresso pass this test as soon as it encounters an object meeting the parameters?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You should be able to create a custom matcher that only matches on the first item with the following code:

```
private <T> Matcher<T> first(final Matcher<T> matcher) {
    return new BaseMatcher<T>() {
        boolean isFirst = true;

        @Override
        public boolean matches(final Object item) {
            if (isFirst && matcher.matches(item)) {
                isFirst = false;
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void describeTo(final Description description) {
            description.appendText("should return first matching item");
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: I want to match nth element, (i.e. second / third etc) how to achieve it?

Comment: I suggest `description.appendText("first item that matches ")` followed by `matcher.describeTo(description)` for a better message when it fails

Answer (score 11):

I created this matcher in case you have many elements with same characteristics like same id, and **if you want not just the first Element** but instead want an **specific Element**. Hope this helps:

```
    private static Matcher<View> getElementFromMatchAtPosition(final Matcher<View> matcher, final int position) {
    return new BaseMatcher<View>() {
        int counter = 0;
        @Override
        public boolean matches(final Object item) {
            if (matcher.matches(item)) {
                if(counter == position) {
                    counter++;
                    return true;
                }
                counter++;
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void describeTo(final Description description) {
            description.appendText("Element at hierarchy position "+position);
        }
    };
}
```

Example:

You have many buttons with same id given from a library you are using, you want to pick the second button.

```
  ViewInteraction colorButton = onView(
            allOf(
                    getElementFromMatchAtPosition(allOf(withId(R.id.color)), 2),
                    isDisplayed()));
    colorButton.perform(click());
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone having the same problem I just had : if you are using the Matcher @appmattus shared to perform one ViewAction, it will be fine, but with multiple ViewActions in the perform, it won't :

```
onView(first(allOf(matcher1(), matcher2()))
      .perform(viewAction1(), viewAction2())
```

`viewAction1` will be executed, but before executing `vewAction2`, the matchers are evaluated again and `isFirst` will always return false. You will get an error stating that no views are matching.

So, here a version working with multiple ViewActions and te possibility to return not just the first one, but the second or third (or...) if you prefer :

```
class CountViewMatcher(val count: Int) : BaseMatcher<View>() {

    private var matchingCount = 0
    private var matchingViewId: Int? = null

    override fun matches(o: Any): Boolean {
        if (o is View) {
            if (matchingViewId != null) {
                // A view already matched the count
                return matchingViewId == o.id
            } else {
                matchingCount++
                if (count == matchingCount) {
                    matchingViewId = o.id
                    return true
                } else {
                    return false
                }
            }
        } else {
            // o is not a view.
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, in your scenario all prices should be in CAD after you have switched the currency. So just grabbing the first item and verifying it should solve your problem too:

```
onData(anything())
        .atPosition(0)
        .onChildView(allOf(withId(R.id.product_price), withText(endsWith("CAD"))))
        .check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```