# Android Espresso perform click on first match

Tags: java, android, android-espresso

Is there a method `firstMatch()` in the Espresso library? Right now I am getting this exception

```
android.support.test.espresso.AmbiguousViewMatcherException matches multiple views in the hierarchy.
```

I have a `RecyclerView` and some of the items are displaying `R.id.textRowBottom`, but not all of it. I want to get the first match and perform a click on it.

It looks like this

```
 onView(allOf(withId(R.id.textRowBottom), isDisplayed())).perform(click());
```

Comment: Are you looking for this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/36866682/1219012

Answer (score 2):

If you want to test items in a RecylerView you could use this:

```
android.support.test.espresso.contrib.RecyclerViewActions
```

So you can select an specific item in the list by its position, something like:

```
onView(withId(recyclerViewId)).perform(
                    RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(0,
                            click(R.id.textRowBottom));
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I am searching for. The position of the items are not fixed.

Comment: click() does not accept R.id.textRowBottom as an argument.