# Tapping the first matching text on a recycler view Android espresso Testing

Tags: android, android-espresso, uitest

I am trying to tap on the first element of a matching text in my app.
However at the moment i am receiving an error telling me there are multiple matches due to my current line of code. 
`onView(allOf(withId(R.id.offerSummaryLayout))).perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItem(Matchers.allOf(hasDescendant(withText("Online sale"))), click()));`

How can I change this so it clicks on the first matching element? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have multiple matches and you only care about the first one, you can create a custom matcher. [This one here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36866682/1993204) should work just fine.

Then you can do things like that (I simplified your code a bit - you don't need `Matchers.allOf` if you have only a single condition):

```
onView(withId(R.id.offerSummaryLayout)).perform(RecyclerViewActions
        .actionOnItem(first(hasDescendant(withText("Online sale"))), click()));
```

Comment: Thanks! However this is still giving me the same error of `AmbiguousViewMatcherException: 'with id: uk.co.vouchercodes.android.beta:id/offerSummaryLayout' matches multiple views in the hierarchy.
Problem views are marked with '****MATCHES****' below.`

Comment: @Billy Boyo is `offerSummaryLayout` the id of the `RecyclerView`?

Comment: @BartekLipinski Yes, the first id is the recyclerView id and works for me !