# How to pass the view to Android Espresso when click?

Tags: android, android-espresso

I want click chatView

> https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/basics

I should code like

`Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers).perform(ViewMatchers).check(ViewAssertions);`

but I got the following error.

```java
        ViewGroup bottomLayoutLeft = mRoomActivity.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.auto_layout_left);
        View chatView = ((ViewGroup) bottomLayoutLeft.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0);
        Espresso.onView((Matcher<View>) chatView).perform(click());
```

Error

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.View cannot be cast to org.hamcrest.Matcher

```java
        ViewGroup bottomLayoutLeft = mRoomActivity.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.auto_layout_left);
        View chatView = ((ViewGroup) bottomLayoutLeft.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0);
        chatView.performClick();
```

Error

> android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Comment: chatView.callOnClick();

Answer (score 0):

first approach is better, but `View chatView` isn't necessary in there. you need a `Matcher` which will find your one and only `View` (which matches conditions, iny our case first item in `bottomLayoutLeft`)

simple matcher example looks like this:

```
onView(allOf(withId(R.id.sample_view), withText("sample text"))).perform(click());
```

but there is a chance, that your `View` doesn't have unique ID, then you should look in [DOCs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/espresso/matcher/ViewMatchers) for constructing proper matcher. it would be easier if you would put in your question your layout structure, then maybe someone will write proper matcher for you (finding `bottomLayoutLeft` probably by id, then gets first child, then again first child)

using `findViewById` (and accessing `View`s strightly) in espresso/layout tests isn't proper way. this is pupropse of tests for look for proper `View`, just like user would do

Comment: no id, no text, this is the reason why I cannot use espresso, thank you for your answer.

Comment: you can use espresso, just write `Matcher` which takes first item from your `ViewGroup` (e.g. like in answers in [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32387137/espresso-match-first-element-found-when-many-are-in-hierarchy))

Answer (score 0):

Use the Barista library for UI tests, it is the easiest solution and makes everything easier. https://github.com/AdevintaSpain/Barista

With Barista, you can do it like this:

```
clickOn("Hello world")
clickOn(R.string.hello_world)
clickOn(R.id.button)
```

You can find more info on the Github page, it covers everything you need.