# Espresso Gives AmbiguousViewMatcher Exception, When Using first(Matcher), I Get NoMatchingViewException

Tags: java, android-espresso

I have a ViewInteraction Query:

```
allOf(withId(R.id.elementId), withText("text"))
```

When I try to query this view, I receive an AmbiguousViewMatcher exception. This is expected as this view is part of a ListView cell.

However, I only want the first result on the page anyway. So, I implemented the function found here: [First Matcher Function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36866682/3596757)

```
public static <T> Matcher<T> first(final Matcher<T> matcher) {
    return new BaseMatcher<T>() {
        boolean isFirst = true;

        @Override
        public boolean matches(final Object item) {
            if (isFirst && matcher.matches(item)) {
                isFirst = false;
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void describeTo(final Description description) {
            description.appendText("should return first matching item");
            matcher.describeTo(description);
        }
    };
}
```

When this function runs on the element, I get the following output:

> androidx.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: should return first matching item(view.getId() is <2131362844/com.myapp:id/elementId> and an instance of android.widget.TextView and view.getText() with or without transformation to match: is "text")

And I'm querying it like so:

```
onView(first(allOf(withId(R.id.elementId), withText("text"))))
```

Does anyone have an idea of why I would go from 8 ambiguous views to no matching views according to this function? I've also added logs, and I'm seeing the view I want go through the function, but it's not detecting it as a match.

What's weirder is that a similar function to this ([found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43552179/3596757)), was working just fine until a month or so ago. Suddenly, both of these functions stopped matching things for us.

Comment: No sure about your issue, but given "This is expected as this view is part of a ListView cell." you should be using `onData` instead of re-inventing wheels: https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/lists

Comment: I was able to get this working via onData. However, I'm still concerned about first() not working. The function should be finding matches, but the line "if (isFirst && matcher.matches(item))" is failing every time.

Comment: You have the full source available - step through with the debugger and see why that is the case.

Comment: I had stepped through the debugger previous to posting this question, seen the matcher go through, but for some reason still not match. I eventually settled on just using onData like your initial recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

There's a built-in function for that purpose

`withParentIndex(int index)`

It is used in cases where multiple child views with the same identifier or type exist within a parent view and the developer wants to interact with a specific child view.

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/espresso/matcher/ViewMatchers#withParentIndex(int)

```
allOf(withId(R.id.elementId), withText("text"), withParentIndex(0))
```